# Hyperledger SBFT vs RBFT

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, consensus

Between the many consensus mechanisms available in Hyperledger, I wish to know the specified difference between the conensus mechanisms in Hyperledger, such as SBFT vs RBFT?

Answer (score 4):

I will let others explain SBFT and RBFT and the many other consensus algorithms.
Hyperledger is composed of 5 different blockchain technologies, each with it's own consensus algorithm.  Here are two supported by Hyperledger Sawtooth:

- **PoET** Proof of Elapsed Time (optional Nakamoto-style consensus algorithm used for Sawtooth). PoET with SGX has BFT. PoET Simulator has CFT. Not CPU-intensive
  as with PoW-style algorithms, although it still can fork and have stale blocks
  . See PoET specification at https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/release
  s/latest/architecture/poet.html
- **RAFT** Consensus algorithm that elects a leader for a term of arbitrary time. Leader replaced if it times-out. Raft is faster than PoET, but is not BFT (Raft is CFT). Also Raft does not fork.

Hyperledger Sawtooth has the advantage of having Unpluggable Consensus.  An algorithm can be changed without reinitializing the blockchain or even restarting the software.

Here are some other consensus algorithms:

- **PoW** Proof of Work. Completing work (CPU-intensive Nakamoto-style consensus algorithm). Usually used in permissionless blockchains
- **PoS** Proof of Stake. Nakamoto-style consensus algorithm based on the most wealth or age (stake)
- **PBFT** Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance. A "classical" consensus algorithm that uses a state machine. Uses leader and block election. PBFT is a three-phase, network-intensive algorithm (n^2 messages), so is not scalable to large networks